# Treeview selected node value is null

Tags: c#, null, treeview

Hello stackoverflow users hope you can help me.

I have populated a treeview control with some data from my database. 
and it works just fine alle the nodes a created but now i need a category id stored in the node. here is a short description of how I make the nodes.

```
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = new TreeNodeCollection();
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        tn.Text =  "<span onclick='return false;'>"+ c.Category_Name +"</span>";
        tn.Value = c.Category_Id.ToString();
        nodes.Add(tn);
```

then when i try to get the value out again for the example here where i will delete the node from the database ill need the selected category id.

```
 protected void btnDeleteCategory_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.Nodes.Remove(TreeView1.SelectedNode);
    string categoryId = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
    // run delete method
}
```

but now the SelectedNode.Value is emty **" "**. but before when i set the value it vasent. 
I was thinking it can be something with when it populate the treeview, but cant see where it should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the id before removing the node.

```
string categoryId = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
TreeView1.Nodes.Remove(TreeView1.SelectedNode);
```

Comment: OMG. really I have to go to sleep. I've been sitting with this for to long when I dident see someting like that! 
but many thanks anyway.